# Updating Kivy Label Using Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, label, kivy, updating

I am trying to make a Kivy label that shows a string that is just a list of names. My end goal is to make it so you can add or remove to the list of names and the label will indicate the names on the list. As of now I have a label and a function in my .py file that compiles the list of names into a string.

Each name in the string is separated by a "\n". My problem however, is that the label does not update and show the names even though the function returns the names. I researched this problem and heard about threading. However, I do not understand how to use it in my case and am asking for some guidance.

Below is my code:

kv CODE:

```
<SettingsWindow>:
name:"settings"
FloatLayout:
Widget:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "Images/logo_br.png"
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,.5
        Rectangle:
            size: 200, 330
            pos: self.width/10, self.height/4
Button:
    text:"Back"
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
    pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0}
    background_color: 1,1,1,.6 
    on_release:
        app.root.current = "main"
        root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
Label:
    text: root.pretty_list_people
    size: self.texture_size
    pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "y":-0.46}
    color: 1,1,1,1
Button:
    text:"Show Bros"  
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
    pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "y":0.1}
    on_press: root.Pretty_Print_People(root.get_str_People())
```

py CODE:

```
class SettingsWindow(Screen):
pretty_list_people = ""

def get_str_Jobs(self):
    return WindowManager.jobs

def get_str_People(self):
    return WindowManager.people

def Pretty_Print_People(self, ppl_list):
    for person in ppl_list:
        self.pretty_list_people += person + "\n"

class HelpWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    jobs = ["Scrub", "Wash", "Clean"]
    people = ["Anthony", "Tim", "John"]
    job_assignments = {}
```

I tried to show only the necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, uses kivy properties:

Change:

```
pretty_list_people = ""
```

To:

```
pretty_list_people = StringProperty ("")
```

And add the import:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
```

At the start of your program

Hope this helps you to solve your problem